# Use of parseBoolean()

Tags: java

I am working on this little thing here and I have a problem with the .parseBoolean(). As arguments, I have (3, true, 8, false, 5, true). Somehow the .parseBoolean doesn't accept the String "true", which is probably why I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
```

Here you have the original code. I probably made some noob fault.

```
package test;

public class CircleExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++) {

            Circle kreis = new Circle();

            double radius = Double.parseDouble(args[i-1]);
            boolean filled = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[i-1]);

            System.out.println(i + ". Kreis:\nRadius: " + radius + "\nUmfang: " + kreis.getCircumference(radius) + "\nFlaeche: " + kreis.getArea(radius));
            if (filled == true){
                System.out.println(i + ". Kreis ist gefuellt.");
            }
            else 
                System.out.println(i + ". Kreis ist nicht gefuellt.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `parseBoolean` throwing the exception and not `parseDouble`?

Comment: You're trying to parse the same argument (`args[i-1]`) as both a Double and a Boolean. Which should it be?

Comment: I just saw it. It's actually the parseDouble that's throwing the exception. 
I know have 2 arrays, but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Double.parseDouble("true") throws an exception bcoz it cannot be converted to a 'double' type

Comment: But this is why I actually don't feed it "true". These are the arguments I'm giving: (3, true, 8, false, 5, true)

Comment: if you see the args are of type String - `String[] args` , you can also understand it by the method that you are invoking - Double.parseDouble(). This takes a string as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
package test;

public class CircleExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // you must increment the variable in 2 units
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i+=2) {

            Circle kreis = new Circle();

            // and select different indexes: i and i+1
            double radius = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
            boolean filled = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[i+1]); 

            System.out.println(i + ". Kreis:\nRadius: " + radius + "\nUmfang: " + kreis.getCircumference(radius) + "\nFlaeche: " + kreis.getArea(radius));
            if (filled == true){
                System.out.println(i + ". Kreis ist gefuellt.");
            }
            else 
                System.out.println(i + ". Kreis ist nicht gefuellt.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the pairwise indexing a little more prominent using something like:

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i < args.length) {
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
        i++;

        boolean filled = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

Before the loop you should also check that you have complete pairs, something like:

```
if (args.length % 2 != 0) {
    System.out.println("Incomplete argument pairs");
}
```